# OpenWeather API Get Current Temp. with Discord.py

Tags: python, openweathermap

I am trying to get the current temperature for my city using the OpenWeather API and Discord.py.

Here is the payload response from the API:

```
{
    "lat": ***,
    "lon": ***,
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "timezone_offset": -18000,
    "current": {
        "dt": 1639881036,
        "sunrise": 1639831807,
        "sunset": 1639866054,
        "temp": 39.4, # This is the value I want! #
        "feels_like": 31.44,
        "pressure": 1020,
        "humidity": 88,
        "dew_point": 36.14,
        "uvi": 0,
        "clouds": 90,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 13.8,
        "wind_deg": 350,
        "wind_gust": 21.85,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 804,
                "main": "Clouds",
                "description": "overcast clouds",
                "icon": "04n"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to make a command that returns the current temperature from the API. Since the API returns in JSON format, I am using string indices to return the current temperature but I'm having trouble with what indexes I have to use to return it correctly.

**My Code:**

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
    async def weather(self, ctx):
        try:
            req = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=****&lon=****&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&units=imperial&appid=****')
            weather = req.text
            for element in weather[5]:
                if element[3] == True:
                    await ctx.send('there')
                    break
                else:
                    await ctx.send('not there')
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(e)
```

I want to find the `current` and return the `temp`, right now I am able to only get it to output `'there'` or `'not there'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the payload from the API response is received in JSON, you need to convert it into a Python readable data format, in this case it would be a Dictionary.

To do so, you can use `json.loads()` on your response.

```py
import json # Don't forget to import the json module!

req = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=****&lon=****&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&units=imperial&appid=****')
weather = req.text
weather = json.loads(weather) # Converts to Python Dict.
```

From there, you can simply access the temperature under the key `'current'` and `'temp'` as such:

```py
currentTemp = weather["current"]["temp"]
```

**Full Code:** *(Remember to `import json`!)*

```py
@commands.command()
@commands.check(is_owner)
    async def weather(self, ctx):
        try:
            req = requests.get('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=****&lon=****&exclude=minutely,hourly,daily&units=imperial&appid=****')
            weather = json.loads(req.text)
            currentTemp = weather["current"]["temp"] # Gets the current temperature.
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(e)
```

As always, remember to validate the JSON response from the API to make sure there is a `temp` in the `current` index, in cases where the lattitude-longitude provided are invalid, or there is no available temperature to report may throw an error because the index won't exist.

Comment: Also, say I wanted to get `currentWeather = weather["current"]["weather"]["description"]` but I get the error of `list indices must be integers or slices, not str` How can I get this to work?